# Converting Bitmap to Icon

Tags: c#, winforms, image, bitmap, icons

I'm trying to convert an image from a `Bitmap` to a Windows icon. This is the code.

```
private void btnCnvrtSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)picturePanel.BackgroundImage;
    Bitmap newBmp = new Bitmap(bmp);
    Bitmap targetBmp = newBmp.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, newBmp.Width, newBmp.Height), PixelFormat.Format64bppArgb);
    IntPtr Hicon = targetBmp.GetHicon();
    Icon myIcon = Icon.FromHandle(Hicon);

    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
    sfd.Title = "Save Icon";
    sfd.Filter = "Icon|*.ico";
    sfd.ShowDialog();

    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(sfd.FileName,FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    myIcon.Save(fileStream);
    fileStream.Flush();
    fileStream.Close();

    MessageBox.Show("Image is converted successfully!");
}
```

The code is working fine but the problem is, when I convert the picture to an icon the converted icon loses its true colors and gradients (shown in image). So, is there any way by which I can convert the image without losing its colors?

This is what my icon looks like.

[image: Before and after converting]

Comment: That looks like the basic 4bpp color palette. I have no idea why it does that though.

Comment: How about creating Icon from handle?

Comment: dont know how to,ok i will try to search in google.If you have any link for an example..please provide.
Thank You.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue with .Net since it doesn't have an icon encoder.  See the following for possible workarounds.

[Create Valid Icon Files](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=396650)

[Convert Bitmap to Icon problem](http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/130238-C-20-convert-Bitmap-to-Icon-problem)