# TreeView Drag & Drop has no dragimage

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, treeview

For a treeview I want to have a drag-image (seems to be called ghostimage sometimes) to enhance the user experience.

Right now there is just have a mouse cursor with an empty rect below of it (where the image should go).

Now I found this [codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9391/Dragging-tree-nodes-in-C) which is very old (2005), so I hope there is something better.

In this [blogpost on drag and drop](http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/488#.UvH-kbS2ydc) the way to go is an adorner, which seems quite complicated for what I want to have, which is just the dragimage.

This is default dragging behaviour in most other UI frameworks I know.

Is there no easier way to get an drag-image than an adorner?

Any comments highly appreciated!

Comment: True drag+drop, not the adorner hack, requires changing the *cursor*.  That used to be tricky until Vista, you can now create one from a PNG image.  So what you have to do is render whatever drag image you want to a PNG and get it saved in the cursor format.  You can get an ugly one from [this kind of code](http://rogers-neighborhood.com/wordpress/?p=55), a pretty one from [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21389253/17034).  Change the 2nd value from 1 to 2.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you very much. Changing the cursor seems to have its own implications. Perhaps the quickest way is following the "adorner hack", at least as I just want the image there.