# Notification icon transparency issues when dragging

Tags: winforms, .net-4.5, transparency, notification-area

I have a WinForms app, the major component of which is an icon down in the notification area. I've noticed that if I drag this icon (to reorder it, or move it to/from the list of icons that are hidden by Windows) then its transparent pixels are not respected correctly, unlike other icons.

This is illustrated in the animation below; other icons look OK when dragged, but my icon (the red circle) does not (excuse the animation's compression artefacts).

[image: Dragging icons]

Looking at that more closely, the icon that normally looks like this:

[image: Thermostat icon]

Looks like this when dragged:

[image: Thermostat icon being dragged]

A [`NotifyIcon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon(v=vs.110).aspx) control is used, and the icon is generated dynamically in various colours and with different numbers overlaid.

In order to maintain translucency around the edges of the icon, [PNG format is used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format)#PNG_format) (using a code sample from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/627823/Fast-and-high-quality-Bitmap-to-icon-converter)) to take a [`Bitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) and return the [`Icon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.icon(v=vs.110).aspx) that is used by the `NotifyIcon`:

```
private static readonly byte[] _pngIconHeader = { 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

using (var bmp = new Bitmap(image, new Size(image.Width, image.Height)))
{
    byte[] png;
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
        ms.Position = 0;
        png = ms.ToArray();
    }

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        _pngIconHeader[6] = (byte)image.Width;
        _pngIconHeader[7] = (byte)image.Height;
        _pngIconHeader[14] = (byte)(png.Length & 255);
        _pngIconHeader[15] = (byte)(png.Length / 256);
        _pngIconHeader[18] = (byte)(_pngIconHeader.Length);

        ms.Write(_pngIconHeader, 0, _pngIconHeader.Length);
        ms.Write(png, 0, png.Length);
        ms.Position = 0;

        return new Icon(ms);
    }
}
```

Is there more that needs to be done to ensure that Windows treats this correctly when it is being dragged?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21389253/17034

Comment: Thanks Hans, but that solution has the same issue when used with a `NotificationIcon`.

Comment: This is out of your control, you'll have to dismiss this as an Explorer bug.  Maybe it behaves better if you create a non-PNG icon but that doesn't exactly help you generate one, the monochrome masking bitmaps are a lot of work.  Set laser to stun or contact your nearest Microsoft representative or congressman.