# c# Create icon from just created image

Tags: c#

I am downloading an image file from some API online.

```
var res = await client.GetAsync(url);
byte[] bytes = await res.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
using (Image image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(bytes)))
{
   image.Save(path + @"\image.jpg");
}
```

After that, I would like to create an icon file from tha downloaded image or the bytes, rather.

I found a function witten by @xiaohuan-zhou that can do it: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57254324/1082692)

```
public void ConvertToIco(Image img, string file, int size)
{
    Icon icon;
    using (var msImg = new MemoryStream())
    using (var msIco = new MemoryStream())
    {
        img.Save(msImg, ImageFormat.Png);
        using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(msIco))
        {
            bw.Write((short)0);           //0-1 reserved
            bw.Write((short)1);           //2-3 image type, 1 = icon, 2 = cursor
            bw.Write((short)1);           //4-5 number of images
            bw.Write((byte)size);         //6 image width
            bw.Write((byte)size);         //7 image height
            bw.Write((byte)0);            //8 number of colors
            bw.Write((byte)0);            //9 reserved
            bw.Write((short)0);           //10-11 color planes
            bw.Write((short)32);          //12-13 bits per pixel
            bw.Write((int)msImg.Length);  //14-17 size of image data
            bw.Write(22);                 //18-21 offset of image data
            bw.Write(msImg.ToArray());    // write image data
            bw.Flush();
            bw.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            icon = new Icon(msIco);
        }
    }
    using (var fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        icon.Save(fs);
    }
}
```

This code was the only one that created an ico file in my case. However, the icon file created have some very thick border around it.
I tried modifying the function but could not get rid of the white borders.

[image]

Comment: What is the value of `size`?

Comment: the size is 500

Comment: You're writing `(byte)size`, so the maximum possible value when written to the file is 255. Maybe try resizing the image to <= 255 first?

Comment: I tried 32 and 48 also, the border won't get away.

Comment: Imagick.NET also produce this wide border when setting is "auto resize". Strange! When I convert the image online, I get a perfect icon. but not in c#

Comment: When you say "I tried 32 and 48", do you mean the image contained in `img` was correctly resized to 32 and 48, or do you mean you just passed a `size` value of 32 or 48?

Comment: I just passed the values. In fact, I can't read the details of the output icon file and it's size is way way bigger than the original jpeg.

Comment: I've never done what you're trying to do, but I would try making sure that the actual dimensions of the image you're passing, and the `size` value are exactly the same, and that the size is <= 255

Comment: So, if I have a jpeg with high and width of (500px), I should resize it first before convert it to icon?

Comment: That tends to happen when SO users do a lousy job [plagiarizing code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21389253/17034).

Comment: Using the code you posted @HansPassant results in creating an ico file that is more than 10 times bigger than the original image. It's just converted it to PNG then changed it's extension to ico with same width and high.